# How can I pass a variable from one function to another in Laravel controller?

Tags: laravel

I have checked other questions similar to this but haven't yet found a working solution. I have my `quantity` variable globally declared at the top of my controller like so:

```php
// defining global quantity variable
private $quantity;
```

I then have my `index()` function, which returns my cart view along with the `quantity` variable. It also checks that if the quantity is 0 then it will be set to 1:

```php
public function index()
{
    $originalQuantity = $this->quantity;

    if ($originalQuantity == 0) {
        $originalQuantity = 1;
    }

    return view('cart.cart', ['quantity' => $originalQuantity]);
}
```

And this is the `web.php` route for this: `Route::get('/cart', [CartController::class, 'index'])->name('cart.index');`

This works and then I run into an issue. I need to pass my `$originalQuantity` into another function that is called when the user hits the increased quantity button. The second function looks like this:

```php
public function increaseQuantity($originalQuantity)
{
    $updatedQuantity = $originalQuantity + 1;
    return view('cart.cart', ['quantity' => $updatedQuantity]);
}
```

This is the route for this function: `Route::patch('/cart', [CartController::class, 'increaseQuantity'])->name('cart.increaseQuantity');`

And the `cart.blade.php` looks like this:

```html
<div class="increase-quantity">
    {{-- PLus button to increase quantity --}}
    <form action="{{ route('cart.increaseQuantity') }}" method="POST">
        @csrf
        @method('PATCH')
        <button type="submit" class="quantity-btn">
            <span class="item-quantity-plus fas fa-plus"></span>
        </button>
    </form>
</div>
```

But when that button is pressed I get an `ArgumentCountError`:

```
Too few arguments to function App\Http\Controllers\CartController::increaseQuantity(), 0 passed in /Users/rosscurrie/mobile-mastery-latest/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Routing/Controller.php on line 54 and exactly 1 expected
```

Here is the error:

[image]

Here are the two methods in the controller and if someone could tell me how to pass the `$originalQuantity` variable properly that would be great:

```php
class CartController extends Controller
{
    // defining global quantity variable
    private $quantity;

    /**
     * Display a listing of the resource.
     *
     * @return Application|Factory|View|int
     */
    public function index()
    {
        $originalQuantity = $this->quantity;

        if ($originalQuantity == 0) {
            $originalQuantity = 1;
        }

        return view('cart.cart', ['quantity' => $originalQuantity]);
    }

    /**
     * Will be called when user hits plus button
     * @param $originalQuantity
     * @return Application|Factory|View
     */
    public function increaseQuantity($originalQuantity)
    {
        $updatedQuantity = $originalQuantity + 1;
        return view('cart.cart', ['quantity' => $updatedQuantity]);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The **error** is coming from the fact that your method signature `increaseQuantity($originalQuantity)` expects one parameter `$originalQuantity` to be passed yet your route declaration `Route::patch('/cart', [CartController::class, 'increaseQuantity'])->name('cart.increaseQuantity');` in `web.php` **NEVER** provides it in a form similar to: `/cart/{originalQuantity}`

A better alternative in my opinion would be to store the `$originalQuantity` value in an [HTTP Session](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/session#storing-data)

i.e:

```php
public function index()
{
    $originalQuantity = $this->quantity;

    if ($originalQuantity == 0) {
        $originalQuantity = 1;
    }

    request()->session()->put('originalQuantity', $originalQuantity);

    return view('cart.cart', ['quantity' => $originalQuantity]);
}
```

```php
public function increaseQuantity()
{
    $updatedQuantity = intval(request()->session()->get('originalQuantity')) + 1;

    return view('cart.cart', ['quantity' => $updatedQuantity]);
}
```

The `web.php` routes then stay the same.

## ADDENDUM

You may find this interesting if you intend to persist the `$updatedQuantity`.
[Incrementing & Decrementing Session Values](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/session##incrementing-and-decrementing-session-values)

Answer (score -1):

You should pass the `$originalQuantity` argument from `cart.blade.php`

```
<div class="increase-quantity">
    {{-- PLus button to increase quantity --}}
    <form action="{{ route('cart.increaseQuantity') }}" method="POST">
        @csrf
        @method('PATCH')
<input type="hidden" name="quantity" value="<?php $updatedQuantity; ?>" />
        <button type="submit" class="quantity-btn">
            <span class="item-quantity-plus fas fa-plus"></span>
        </button>
    </form>
</div>
```

Comment: This is not what I am having the issue with, the issue is in the actual controller